# Changing image projection using Python

Tags: python, dictionary, google-maps, map-projections

Image corner coordinates are known:

- Top left: (70.20315, 20.92749)
- Top right: (70.20315, 31.45240)
- Bottom left: (59.70571, 20.92749)
- Bottom right: (59.70571, 31.45240)

(Basically map over Finland and a little bit of Sweden/Norway/Russia)

I couldn't find a way to change image projection to Google maps overlay image, preferably using Python.

It's possible to do that with [pyproj](https://web.archive.org/web/20141226153942/https://code.google.com/p/pyproj/) and [PIL](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111170816/https://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/), but I wasn't able to figure out how to do that. I also found [GDAL](https://gdal.org/), and more specifically [gdalwarp](https://gdal.org/gdalwarp.html), but couldn't find options for changing projection in a correct way.

[image: Example image]

Comment: Can you show the code that you are currently using to put the image overlay into Google maps?  If your Python is in turn calling JavaScript, it should be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Copy-paste from [gis](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10430/changing-image-projection-using-python) answer)

Extensive trial-and-error showed it worked fine without specifying source projection. Same can be achieved using only GDAL Python API. Steps to reproduce:

Adding control points to TIF (of course, first `convert mapimage.png mapimage.tif`):

```
gdal_translate mapimage.tif mapimage_georeffed.tif -gcp 2300 2300 31.45240 59.70571 -gcp 0 0 20.92749 70.20315 -gcp 2300 0 31.45240 70.20315 -gcp 0 2300 20.92749 59.70571 -a_srs +proj=longlat
```

Then, GDAL python bindings include `gdal2tiles.py`, which autogenerates tiles on right projection for maps, and also sample map pages.

For the record, I'm not absolutely positive projection is exactly correct, but over that area it seems to be at least good enough.